# NodeJS Rest API with Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase-hosting

I am writing my backend rest api using Node and Express. I have defined an end-point like “localhost:3000/products”. A get request to this end point returns all the products in the database as a json response.

This works fine on my local system. Now I want to deploy it to firebase.

So here is what I did:

1. Installed firebase cli tools
2. Initialized my project and selected my project from the options provided by firebase cli
3. For public directory I selected “public”
4. Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
5. Finally “firebase deploy”

But when I hit the new end-point “https://.firebaseapp.com/products” with a get request, I get a HTML response which is the index.html and not the json response of products (like on my local system).

I created another end-point “localhost:3000/welcome” which responds with a simple welcome message. This works in local system but not in firebase.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did everything right.
You should try now, it may work. Actually 5 days back there were severe issues in firebase functions & hosting, but not with Firebase database. So, everything was perfect on your local systems, but your page was not rendered when deployed.